# How do I remove non numeric characters from only one column of a .csv file in bash?

Tags: bash, csv, awk, sed

I have a large .csv file containing inconsistent data that looks something like this:

```
O_T_11c,234858DEF8,OHL11_c_234858DEF8.csv,c
Ohl12und,234858DEF8,OHL12_u234858DEF8.csv,u
Ohlabx13und,234858DEF8,OHL13u_234858DEF8.csv,u
Ohl14und,234858DEF8,OHL14u_234858DEF8.csv,u
```

I want to remove the all letters only from only the first column and leave the rest alone. I've attempted to do this using a regex in awk, but this gives me
strange output. I want my output to ultimately be this:

```
11,234858DEF8,OHL11_c_234858DEF8.csv,c
12,234858DEF8,OHL12_u234858DEF8.csv,u
13,234858DEF8,OHL13u_234858DEF8.csv,u
14,234858DEF8,OHL14u_234858DEF8.csv,u
```

I understand I can use a sed like this

```
sed 's/[^0-9]*//g'
```

To remove all non-numeric characters, but I only want to apply this to the first column.

Comment: Use this `sed -i 's/^[^0-9]\+//;s/[^0-9 ]\+  */  /' largefile.csv`

Comment: @alvits This is great, and with a couple of edits (needed because my question wasn't clear) this is what I used. Can you give a quickie explanation of how it works and how its constrained to the first row and post it as an answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Now that we know the actual input is comma delimited, here's the quickest solution to your question.

```
sed -i 's/^[^0-9]\+//;s/[^0-9,]\+//' largefile.csv
```

`s/^[^0-9]\+//` -  will remove any non-numeric from the start of the line.

`s/[^0-9,]\+//` - will remove any non-numeric trailing the numbers just before the comma.

Answer (score 2):

Short ***awk*** approach:

```
awk -F, '{ gsub(/[^0-9]/,"",$1) }1' OFS=',' file
```

The output:

```
11,234858DEF8,OHL11_c_234858DEF8.csv,c
12,234858DEF8,OHL12_u234858DEF8.csv,u
13,234858DEF8,OHL13u_234858DEF8.csv,u
14,234858DEF8,OHL14u_234858DEF8.csv,u
```

Comment: this prints out a bunch of numbers, but doesn't give me the output that I want, which is the file itself edited as described.

Comment: I think the input file is comma separated not space delimited. That's the only rationale the code will yield a different output. Hence the name csv file.

Comment: @alvits, that means that he posted non-actual wrong input

Comment: @alvits You're  correct. I foolishly just copied and pasted from excel, which gives data that looks space delimited, but it isn't.